# Using zabbix calculated items within template

Tags: zabbix

I have a Zabbix monitoring template, which defines a number of items, plus an additional calculated item.

The template is `T extern`.

This defines some active checks using an external script, that run every 10min, return a single integer, and have the name formats:

```
T extern:script.pl["{HOST.IP}","foo"]
T extern:script.pl["{HOST.IP}","foo"]
```

So far, this all works, the checks run correctly, and data is updated.

Now I try and define a calculate field in the template called `T extern:summary`, updating every 5min, with the formula:

```
( last("T extern:script.pl[\"{HOST.IP}\",\"foo\"]") + last("T 
extern:script.pl[\"{HOST.IP}\",\"bar\"]") ) / 2
```

However, this fails to work and the item always has an unknown value.

What am I doing wrong in the configuration?

Comment: I can always tell when I'm about to solve a problem - its just after I get to the point where I post the question on stackexchange ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that, when defining a calculated field in a template, you *do not* include the template name (though you *do* include it if you're defining a trigger).  So, the correct formula was:

```
( last("script.pl[\"{HOST.IP}\",\"foo\"]")
    + last("script.pl[\"{HOST.IP}\",\"bar\"]")
) / 2
```